# Deleting items in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Before `deleteData()` method was called, I've verified that there are two instances in my Core Data. Now I need to delete one away. I referred to this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-managed-objects-and-fetch-requests--cms-25068) to delete my core data.

I managed to copy the first `NSManagedObject` instance through `let person = people[0] as! NSManagedObject` through this code, but app terminated on this line `managedContext.delete(person)`.

The error faced was `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObjectContext delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fefe28092e0'`

```
func deleteData() {
    var people = [Particulars]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Particulars")
    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    do {
        people = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Particulars]
        do {
            let person = people[0] as! NSManagedObject
            managedContext.delete(person)
            try managedContext.save()

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not delete data \(error)")
                }
    } catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Could not fetch data \(error)")
        }
}
```

Comment: Try `managedContext.deleteObject(person)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper call is not <strike>`delete`</strike>, but **`deleteObject`** for `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Also note that it is more readable to write `person.first` rather than `people[0]`, but it is of course a matter of taste.

I think `let person = people[0] as! NSManagedObject` is problematic, because

1. It is not safe and would crash if there are no search results. Use `if let person = people.first`...
2. The downcast from `Particulars` to `NSManagedObject` also does not make sense. You have already performed a cast when getting the search results.

Comment: Well I'm new to swift, and so I followed the tutorial how it was taught. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I hear you. Some tutorials out there are riddled with mistakes.